# Write an hours2days function in python

Tags: python

Write an hours2days function that takes one argument, an integer, that is a time period in hours. The function should return a tuple of how long that period is in days and hours, with hours being the remainder that can't be expressed in days.

My code looks like this:

```
def hours2days(hours):
    days = hours // 24
    hours = hours % 24
    print(days, hours)

hours2days(39)
```

anyone has any other suggestions?

Comment: Return the tuple instead of printing it inside the function

Comment: It's perfectly fine working. Why do you need to change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I have one -- use `divmod`:

```
In [16]: def hours2days(hours):
    ...:     return divmod(hours, 24)
    ...: 

In [17]: days, hrs = hours2days(39)

In [18]: days
Out[18]: 1

In [19]: hrs
Out[19]: 15
```

Answer (score 0):

## What about a dictionary?

I thought this could be more explicit about the result.

```
def hours2days(hours):
    days, hours = divmod(hours, 24)
    return {"days": days, "hours": hours}

>>> hours2days(39)
{'days': 1, 'hours': 15}
```